# Difference between import numpy and import numpy as np

Tags: python, numpy

I understand that when possible one should use

```
import numpy as np
```

This helps keep away any conflict due to namespaces. But I have noticed that while the command below works

```
import numpy.f2py as myf2py
```

the following does not

```
import numpy as np
np.f2py #throws no module named f2py
```

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: @roippi have you tried exit your python and enter it and just do `import numpy` then `numpy.f2py` ? It throws an error in my case too

Comment: Importing a module doesn't import sub-modules. You need to explicitly import the `numpy.f2py` module regardless of whether or not/how `numpy` itself has been imported.

Answer (score 22):

**numpy** is the top package name, and doing `import numpy` doesn't import submodule `numpy.f2py`.

When you do `import numpy` it creats a link that points to `numpy`, but `numpy` is not further linked to `f2py`. The link is established when you do `import numpy.f2py`

In your above code:

```
import numpy as np # np is an alias pointing to numpy, but at this point numpy is not linked to numpy.f2py
import numpy.f2py as myf2py # this command makes numpy link to numpy.f2py. myf2py is another alias pointing to numpy.f2py as well
```

Here is the difference between `import numpy.f2py` and `import numpy.f2py as myf2py`:

- `import numpy.f2py`

  - put **numpy** into local symbol table(pointing to numpy), and numpy is linked to numpy.f2py
  - both **numpy** and **numpy.f2py** are accessible
- `import numpy.f2py as myf2py`

  - put **my2py** into local symbol table(pointing to numpy.f2py)
  - Its parent numpy is not added into local symbol table. Therefore you can not access numpy directly

Answer (score 18):

The `import as` syntax was introduced in [PEP 221](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/) and is well documented there.

When you import a module via

```
import numpy
```

the numpy package is bound to the local variable `numpy`. The `import as` syntax simply allows you to bind the import to the local variable name of your choice (usually to avoid name collisions, shorten verbose module names, or standardize access to modules with compatible APIs).

Thus,

```
import numpy as np
```

is equivalent to,

```
import numpy
np = numpy
del numpy
```

When trying to understand this mechanism, it's worth remembering that `import numpy` actually means `import numpy as numpy`.

When importing a *submodule*, you must refer to the full parent module name, since the importing mechanics happen at a higher level than the local variable scope. i.e.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.f2py   # OK
import np.f2py      # ImportError
```

I also take issue with your assertion that "where possible one should [import numpy as np]". This is done for historical reasons, mostly because people get tired very quickly of prefixing every operation with `numpy`. It has never prevented a name collision for me (laziness of programmers actually suggests there's a higher probability of causing a collision with `np`)

Finally, to round out my exposé, here are 2 interesting uses of the `import as` mechanism that you should be aware of:

#### 1. long subimports

```
import scipy.ndimage.interpolation as warp
warp.affine_transform(I, ...)
```

#### 2. compatible APIs

```
try:
    import pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft as fft
except:
    import numpy.fft as fft
# call fft.ifft(If) with fftw or the numpy fallback under a common name
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a language feature. `f2py` is a subpackage of the module `numpy` and must be loaded separately.

This feature allows:

- you to load from `numpy` only the packages you need, speeding up execution.
- the developers of `f2py` to have namespace separation from the developers of another subpackage.

Notice however that `import numpy.f2py` or its variant `import numpy.f2py as myf2py` are still loading the parent module `numpy`.

Said that, when you run

```
import numpy as np
np.f2py
```

You receive an `AttributeError` because `f2py` is not an attribute of `numpy`, because the `__init__()` of the package `numpy` did not declare in its scope anything about the subpackage `f2py`.

Comment: when you do `import numpy.f2py as myf2py`, how do you access its parent numpy? it seems `import numpy.f2py` allows you to access its parent `numpy`, but `import numpy.f2py as myf2py` doesn't

Comment: You don't access it because you decided you didn't want to use anything from `numpy`, and you only care of using the subpackage. It is similar to using `from foo import bar`: the name `foo` will not be accessible. See the comment after the first example of the docs, [LINK](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.f2py` is actually a submodule of `numpy`, and therefore has to be imported separately from numpy. As [aha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2583917/aha) said before:

> When you do import numpy it creats a link that points to numpy, but
>   numpy is not further linked to f2py. The link is established when you
>   do import numpy.f2py

when you call the statement `import numpy as np`, you are shortening the phrase "numpy" to "np" to make your code easier to read. It also helps to avoid namespace issues. (tkinter and ttk are a good example of what can happen when you do have that issue. The UIs look extremely different.)

Answer (score 1):

Well quite an old post but here are my 2 cents over the explanation provided by others.

numpy (refer git repository) package have various subpackages, f2py is one of them other are as core, ma etc

If you refer the **init**.py in numpy package it has imports like -

```
from . import core etc
```

but it's not having any import for f2py subpackage.
That's the reason that a statement like

```
import numpy as np
np.f2py
```

won't work but

```
import numpy as np
np.core
```

will work.

Comment: The most direct answer, and provides the mechanism. Just as useful to today as 4 or 7 years ago..