# Differences in importing modules/subpackages of numpy and Scipy packages

Tags: python, numpy, import, scipy

I am using scipy and numpy through Anaconda 2.1.0 distribution. I use Spyder as my Python IDE.

When I run  `import scipy as sp`,  I can't access the subpackages, such as optimize, linalg, cluster etc. through `sp.`

However, when I run `import numpy as np`, I am able to access all its subpackages, such as linalg, random, matrixlib, polynomial, testing, etc. through `np`.

Is there a reason why the two imports work in different ways?  Why does `import scipy as sp` not grab all scipy subpackages into `sp`'s namespace?

Comment: This is indeed an interesting question. Funny thing is: After `import scipy as sp` typing `sp.optimize` will give you an error. But if you do `from scipy import optimize`, suddenly `sp.optimize` won't give you an error anymore. This problem is not specific to anaconda.

Comment: @cel, you don't get anymore the error because when you type `from scipy import optimize`, the interpreter realizes that it has already loaded the main package `scipy`, and it will import the submodule `optimize` within that already loaded module. The identifier `sp` is pointing to that same module as before that is now 'updated', so that you can now access the submodule `optimize` through the identifier as well.

Comment: Historically, `numpy` is the basic, integrated numeric package.  `scipy` is a collection of independently developed scientific packages.  They all make use of `numpy`, but don't depend on each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This possibility of different import behaviour occurs by design of the python language.

An import statement of a module(*) by default only imports the main module, and not the submodules. The main module may (like in the case of `numpy`) , or may not (like `scipy`) import some or all the submodules.

The reason behind this is exemplified by `scipy`: in most cases, you will need only one submodule of the `scipy` package. This default behaviour will not hang the interpreter at loading submodules that are unnecessary to your code.

EDIT:
Notice that `numpy` does not import by default all the submodules, for example it does not load `numpy.f2py`, see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622571/difference-between-import-numpy-and-import-numpy-as-np/22622968#22622968) question/answer for more details.

(*) here I mean an import statement like `import scipy` or `import scipy as sp`, where a module is loaded. Of course if you write `import scipy.optimize` then python will first load the main module, and then the submodule.

Comment: Thanks.  So, what would be one simple expression to load all the submodules for any module under any identifier the user wants?

Comment: There is for sure a way, but it is a bad idea. Just import the modules you need. I would say that if you don't know in advance which submodules you're going to need from a certain module you have a bigger problem, in the sense that you don't know what you are doing

Comment: you may be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707709/list-all-the-modules-that-are-part-of-a-python-package) question though

Comment: I'm also trying to do this but I can't load the interpolate submodule. It says this "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."