# Error importing scipy as sp when I use sp.integrate.quad()

Tags: python, scipy

I'm getting an error when importing `scipy` into Python. When I write:

```
import scipy as sp
x2 = lambda x: x**2
print sp.integrate.quad(x2, 0, 4)
```

I get the error:

```
sp.integrate.quad: "NameError: name 'integrate' is not defined".
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing `scipy` does not automatically load the `integrate` subpackage. Use:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
```

or

```
import scipy.integrate as spi
```

and use `spi.quad`

From the docs (or, rather, SciPy's `__init__.py` file):

> ```
> ...
> Subpackages
> -----------
> Using any of these subpackages requires an explicit import.  For example,
> ``import scipy.cluster``.
>
> ::
>
>  cluster                      --- Vector Quantization / Kmeans
>  fftpack                      --- Discrete Fourier Transform algorithms
>  ...
>  integrate                    --- Integration routines [*]
>  ...
> ```

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744767/differences-in-importing-modules-subpackages-of-numpy-and-scipy-packages) question about why is that

Comment: Thanks both of you, for the solution and for the aditional info in that other question.