# importing whole python module doesn't allow using submodules

Tags: python, numpy, import, module, scikit-learn

My question is specific to scikit-learn python module, but I had similar issues with matplotlib as well.

When I want to use sklearn, if I just do 'import sklearn' and then call whatever submodule I need, like ' sklearn.preprocessing.scale()', I get an error 
"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'preprocessing'"

On the other hand, when I do 'from sklearn import preprocessing'
and then use 'preprocessing.scale()' it works normally.

When I use other modules like Numpy, it is sufficient to just 'import numpy' and it works well.

Therefore, I would like to ask if anyone can tell me why is this happening and if I am doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9049246/4014959) may be helpful.

Comment: The proposed duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048518/importing-packages-in-python, is asking about 'how do I structure my own package to import all'.  Here the question is about the behavior of `scikit-learn`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744767/differences-in-importing-modules-subpackages-of-numpy-and-scipy-packages is a better duplicate, since it focuses on the difference between `numpy` and `scipy`.  `scipy` like `scikit-learn` requires importing submodules individually.

Answer (score 2):

A python package is defined in the `__init__.py` file inside the directory.
This file determines whether or not submodules are include.

When you do `import sklearn` python finds the file `sklearn/__init__.py` and executes it to create the `sklearn` module. This object is the bound to the name `sklearn`. **Submodules are not implicitly imported by the interpreter.**

However when doing `from sklearn import preprocessing` python will first load the `sklearn` module as before. Then it will check if `preprocessing` is an attribute of that module (e.g. a function), and if not it will look for the file `sklearn/preprocessing.py` and improt that module too.

It happens that `numpy` does something like the following in its `__init__.py` file:

```
import .random
```

Thus when importing numpy as `import numpy` the execution of that module triggers the importing of `numpy.random` which is then added as an attribute.

---

This is useful because sometimes you want to use only part of a package and loading all of it could take a significant amount of time. For example importing `numpy` *does* take something like half a second. This is time wasted if you only need a very small subset of its functionality.

---

You may be interested in reading the [documentation for packages](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Answer (score 1):

Numpy conveniently imports its submodules in its `__init__.py` file and adds them to `__all__`. There's not much you can do about it when using a library - it either does it or not. sklearn apparently doesn't.