# Missing interpolate in scipy 0.17

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using `scipy 0.17.1` and `numpy 1.11.1`.
I am getting an error when trying to use `interpolate`, even if the subpackage interpolate should be included in my version ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/interpolate.html#))

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(x) + 0.01*np.random.randn(1, 1000)
y = scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator(x, y)
```

Results in error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\flabriol\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-110-7dfbae0fdab5>", line 5, in <module>
    y = scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator(x, y)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'interpolate'
```

Can I use the `interpolate` module without upgrading `scipy`?

Comment: Should be available. Perhaps you have to `import scipy.interpolate`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As per the scipy source - you need to explicitly import the subpackage:

> ### Subpackages
>
> Using any of these subpackages requires an explicit import.  For example,
>   `import scipy.cluster`.

So changing (or adding)

```
import scipy.interpolate
```

should fix it for you

Comment: Just wondering if you or anyone else happens to know why scipy is like this.  Numpy is not: I can call numpy.random.rand without the explicit import of numpy.random.

Comment: @saintsfan342000 - This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744767/differences-in-importing-modules-subpackages-of-numpy-and-scipy-packages) and answer may shed some light: In particular this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744767/differences-in-importing-modules-subpackages-of-numpy-and-scipy-packages#comment43908729_27744767) probably has the key point (ie design decision)